# Problem with ri + rvm + Textmate

Tags: ruby, textmate, rvm, ri

I'm trying to lookup help for Ruby methods in Textmate through the Ctrl+H shortcut, but I'm always getting this error:

> /Users/tomdeleu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:388:in
>   `bin_path': can't find gem rdoc ([">=
>   0"]) with executable ri
>   (Gem::GemNotFoundException) from
>   /Users/tomdeleu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ri:19:in`
>   '

Platform:

- MacOS X 10.6.8
- RVM 1.6.20
- Textmate 1.5.10 (1631)
- TM_RUBY set to /Users/tomdeleu/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby
- installed osx-plist update as detailed in the [RVM integration docs](http://beginrescueend.com/integration/textmate/)
- installed [DrNic's Rails bundle](https://github.com/drnic/ruby-on-rails-tmbundle)

Ri works fine from the command-line (I ran "rvm docs generate" to install docs for 1.9.2).
I've searched around but can't find a solution. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching (and asking) around, solved it by reinstalling both Textmate (including delete of all customizations), and Ruby 1.9.2 (through RVM). 
Afterwards I installed the osx-plist update + some bundles again. Note that the osx-plist update (as detailed [here](http://beginrescueend.com/integration/textmate/)) should be done with system Ruby, not a Ruby 1.9, otherwise other errors occur. 
Also in Textmate make sure the PATH variable *does not* have a custom Ruby before your system Ruby.
With these settings, everything works fine now. Hopefully this is useful to anyone encountering this error in the future...